# Vim 'w' behaving like 'W'

Tags: vim

I use vim.  On every machine I have ever used it on, 'w' respects punctuation.  If I press 'w', I will advance to the end of a word.

In the case of a period delimited word, I will move to the next period.

However, in a particular install of vim, 'w' is interpreted as 'W' and skips past all special characters.

At first I thought I would just adapt, but it has become frustrating.  How do I return this behavior to normal?

Comment: What version of vi or vim is it? :ve

Comment: @Ram VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4

Comment: have you or some plugin that you installed changed `iskeyword` ?

Comment: @blues i have not, but maybe the installer of this did

Comment: You can see the value of a config by adding a ? at the end. `:set iskeyword?` and compare the output to that of a vim installation that behaves as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remapping this. Go to your ~/.vimrc and add this and save:

```
nnoremap w w
```

Comment: this seems to work for all cases except a dot-delimited name i.e. `foo.bar`, 'w' advances from start of foo to start of next word past bar

Comment: what is the output of :nmap ?

Comment: `n  W      * w`  this is the output mapping

Comment: try `nnoremap w w` and see what the effect is?

Comment: This would mean _something_ remaps your `w`, as `nnoremap w w` restores the original meaning. If you want to know what it is, remove `nnoremap w w`, restart Vim, and execute `:verbose nmap w`. (I'd rather find the real cause, than slap a band-aid over it.)

Comment: @Amadan agreed. real answer is provided by Ingo Karkat. Stop the bleeding first... treat the underlying cause later.

Answer (score 5):

What `w` skips over is controlled by [`:help 'iskeyword'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27iskeyword%27). Now if Vim suddenly skips past periods, that means that the period (`.`, or numerical `46`) got added to that option.

You can find out where this was done via

```
:verbose setlocal iskeyword?
```

And (for the current session) undo with

```
:setlocal isk-=. isk-=46
```

Usually, a *filetype plugin* changes this for a particular type of file.